# Javascript Not Displaying Button Text

Tags: javascript, html, dialogflow-es

full json is

```
    {
"id": "70dec1ac-345f-4b94-b255-b09c5ab1b522",
"name": "card",
"auto": true,
"contexts": [],
 "responses": [
{
  "resetContexts": false,
  "affectedContexts": [],
  "parameters": [],
  "messages": [
    {
      "type": 1,
      "platform": "facebook",
      "title": "this is the title updated",
      "subtitle": "this is the subtitle",
      "imageUrl": "https://www.gettyimages.ie/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg",
      "buttons": [
        {
          "text": "this is the button"
        },
        {
          "text": "this is also a button"
        }
      ],
      "lang": "en"
    },
    {
      "type": 0,
      "speech": []
    }
  ],
  "defaultResponsePlatforms": {},
  "speech": []
}
],
"priority": 500000,
"cortanaCommand": {
"navigateOrService": "NAVIGATE",
"target": ""
},
"webhookUsed": false,
"webhookForSlotFilling": false,
"lastUpdate": 1530197695,
"fallbackIntent": false,
"events": [],
"userSays": [
{
  "id": "528c22d4-49d7-4ab9-a8db-fcd84d57694b",
  "data": [
    {
      "text": "card"
    }
  ],
  "isTemplate": false,
  "count": 0,
  "updated": 1530196620,
  "isAuto": false
}
],
"followUpIntents": [],
"templates": []
}
```

I am actually making a chatbot for wordpress to communicate with api.ai or dialogflow 
The code I am currently using to display a card is the following:

```
var html = "<div class=\"myc-conversation-bubble myc-conversation-response myc-is-active myc-image-response\"><img src=\"" + imageUrl + "\"/></div>";
html+="<div class=\"myc-card-title\">" + title + "</div>"
html += "<div class=\"myc-card-subtitle\">" + subtitle+ "</div>";
html += "<input type=\"button\" " + "style=\"background-color:rgb(221, 153, 51);text-transform: none\"" + "class=\"myc-quick-reply\" value=\"" +buttons[0]+ "\" />";
var innerHTML = "<div class=\"myc-conversation-bubble-container myc-conversation-bubble-container-response\"><div class=\"myc-conversation-bubble myc-conversation-response myc-is-active myc-quick-replies-response\">" + html + "</div>";
```

I am getting the image ,title ,subtitle correctly but the Button is displayed as [object Object] what is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Provide the full `JSON`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The button text is in the `text` property.

Try to replace `buttons[0]` with `buttons[0].text`.

Answer (score 0):

in your case buttons is an array of object and have property text. so try `buttons[0].text`